# F#: recursive function to find bigger value in non empty list

Tags: list, recursion, f#, highest

I need a recursive function in F# that gives me the biggest value of a non empty list.
example:

```
biggest [2;4;5;3;9;3]
```

should return 9

Update 1

I'm learning recursive functions and this is an exercise from the book with no answer on it. I thought it was ok to ask here but it seems it was not a good idea. Ok, I didn't write any code example so that it seemed to be a homework exercise of a lazy guy. Anyway this is my best try:

```
let rec highest l = 
    match l with 
    |[] -> 0 
    |x::y::xs -> if x > y then highest x::xs
                 else highest y::xs
```

But this doesn't work. I cannot use F# functions, this is for learning purpose of course. So sorry if made you loose some time and thanks for your help.

Comment: If this is homework, please indicate so in the question. Otherwise the people who answer don't have the right context.

Comment: Why should it be recursive? List.max does what you want.

Comment: @hvester probably because that's the homework assignment.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'm learning recursive functions in F# and tried many things, I guess this is the best 
    `let rec highest l =`
     `match l with`
     `[] -> 0`
     `|x::y::xs -> if x>y then highest x::xs`
                      `else highest y::xs`
But doesn't work

Comment: @FyodorSoikin it's an exercise from the book to learn recursion, but has no solution, thanks for the tip

Comment: @mydogisbox it's just an exercise, not really homework, thanks

Comment: The update makes this a much better question.  The next step in making it even better is replacing "But this doesn't work." with details on exactly how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the answer: this question is weird and Stackoverflow is probably not the best place for it.

- If it's for production code, use `List.max`. (Puns aside, recursion isn't its own reward...)
- If it's for homework, try to understand recursion instead of delegating your exercises to random people on the internet.
- If it's a puzzle/code golf, this is the wrong site and it could be clearer what the requirements are.

Anyway, this *can* be answered as posted, with the following requirements:

- The solution is tail-recursive, not just recursive. Obviously I don't want to write a function to replace `List.max` just to needlessly grow the stack.
- The function `biggest` that is called in the question's code is *directly* the recursive one and gets no additional arguments. If I take the question literally, this seems to be a requirement, so I'm not allowed to use an accumulator.

[`List.max` is implemented with a mutating loop and therefore doesn't qualify (link goes to F# source code)](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs). So this needs a custom implementation:

```
let rec biggest = function
    | h1 :: h2 :: t -> biggest ((max h1 h2) :: t)
    | [result] -> result
    | [] -> failwith "list empty"
```

It's a pretty weird solution, but it does what's asked for and works for long lists.

Comment: Why didn't you use an inner function with an accumulator to fullfill the "signature requirement" without having to "be weird" ?

Comment: @Vandroiy Your code is what was looking for, I was close to your answer but something was wrong in my code. 
I'm just learning recursion, don't want to bother people on the internet, my excuses if I did it with you.
Thank you very much

Comment: @Sehnsucht that might be cheating. The function called in the question should be recursive, not a function that's being called by it. The requirement of being recursive is arbitrary anyway, so the stricter rule might just as well be the correct one. So of course I use the strictest interpretation. :P

Comment: @Seb No worries, I don't feel bothered; I just want to be sure that my answers do more good than harm. Stackoverflow sometimes has questions that look like attempts to short-cut understanding and just get something to "work". Of course I don't know your intentions, I just want to suggest to focus on "why" questions and concepts rather than specific solutions. I wish you all the best with your learning!

Answer (score 1):

After some days thinking on it and with some help at school I came up with this, it's an alternative solution to Vandroiy's one:

```
let rec max_value l =
    match l with
    |[] -> []
    |[x] -> [x]
    |(x::y::xs) ->  if x<y then max_value (y::xs)
                    else max_value (x::xs)
```

thanks a lot